# React.addons.cloneWithProps chaining of event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why and how `React.addons.cloneWithProps` does chaining of event handlers?

```
// All props were transferred from <Element /> to its child.
// Event handlers from <Element /> will chain with event handlers from its child.
var Case2 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
        return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, this.props);
    }
});

// All props were transferred from <Element /> to its child.
// Event handlers from <Element /> will override event handlers from its child.
var Case3 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
        return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, _.omit(this.props, 'children'));        
    }
});
```

Here is the [official documentation of the React.addons.cloneWithProps](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html). It says nothing about this behavior.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1vge7pr/).